# How to boot into Boot Camp Windows 10 recovery mode (MBP 2019 Intel)

Tags: windows, bootcamp

I have a MacBook Pro 2019 Intel, running Catalina.  I have Windows 10 installed with Boot Camp (using Boot Camp Assistant).  Windows stopped booting (kept going into a loop, Windows 10 auto recovery mode didn't help) so I had to redo it (deleted the Boot Camp partition and created it again).  I had a scare where it was doing the same loop thing with Windows 10 auto recovery, but then it finally booted up normally.

I created a Windows 10 USB installation media via the [Windows Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

How can I go into my own Windows recovery mode or safe mode?  Difficult since MacBook Pro doesn't have the same BIOS as Windows.  How can I actually launch Windows 10 recovery mode on my MacBook Pro Intel?  I held down <kbd>Opt</kbd> when the Mac is starting up, I choose EFI Boot (I assume this is the bootable USB drive), but when I choose it, it goes into Mac Boot Recovery Assistant and says "Security settings do not allow this Mac to use an external startup disk.  You can change this by restarting and holding down Command-R to open MacOS recovery, and then choosing Startup Security Utility." and then two buttons **Startup Disk...** and **Restart**.  Clicking **Startup Disk...** just gives the option for Boot Camp or Mac HD.

Comment: Why did you not use the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows 10?

Comment: I have Safari, FireFox and Edge installed on my Mac. When I click on your link [Windows Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), I do not get anything related to the Windows Creation Tool. The link takes to a Microsoft website to download the current Windows 10 ISO (version 22H2). Did you try clicking on this link from a Mac running macOS?

Comment: thank you for your reply.  1 - I did use boot camp assistant.  2- the link when i run on windows has an option "Using the tool to create installation media (USB flash drive, DVD, or ISO file) to install Windows 10 on a different PC (click to show more or less information)".  3 the issue is when windows goes into a loop with recovery mode, I want to be able to boot into windows safe mode or recovery mode so I can do things myself.

Comment: If Windows does not boot properly it is going to be difficult, to say the least, to get into safe mode. You could try holding the shift key when Windows starts to boot, but failing that your best bet is to go back to Boot Camp and reinstall right over the top of your current Windows installation. Windows is smart enough these days to not wipe out user files/settings when reinstalling so just reinstalling with Boot Camp is your best bet.

Comment: ok thanks, but i dont see that option in boot camp assistant - can only remove the existing windows partition, not re-run setup, any specifics how to do this? thanks